# Flutter How to create pixel-art?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Imagine this, where I can render a picture as a canvas & then interact with whatever pixel I want.

Firstly I'd need to parse the pixels somehow, I've tried parsing this picture by it's on-picture pixel amount by using filesize/12x12 & trying to only render sub-lists of the bytes with Image.memory, but it didn't really work out well since it still doesn't make the pixels interactable & it renders it top-down. Maybe I would need to use an image that's true to size pixel amount instead but I'd then need to upscale it somehow.

Do I map each pixel to an container widget? Do I use the flutter canvas library? Im pretty confused.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app,you want code like that??
: https://apps.apple.com/vn/app/pixel-art-editor-for-mcpe/id1603567060

**EDIT:**

First: you need this: https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
img.Image image = img.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
image.setPixelSafe(x,y,color);// this line draw a color to pixel at x,y
```

next step paint image to **canvas** or **Image.memory()**

Comment: Something like that yeah.